# Asking a question in german, when to use 'zu'

Tags: grammar, formality, question

The example that I would like to use is:

`Um welche Uhr es ist möglich für uns zu treffen am Dienstag (Morgen)?`

Googling that question as well as using Google translate suggests that this is not the correct syntax.

If somebody can explain the grammar rules as well as the logic of formulating those kind of questions, it could be very helpful for me.

Comment: Short answer: An infinitive that is not preceded by one of a certain list of modal verbs requires a *zu*. Switching verbs can remove the *zu*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little broad as there's not really an explicit question; I'll try to address a few issues in your sentence, though.

First, you'd ask "zu welcher (Uhr)Zeit" or "um welche (Uhr)Zeit". If you want to use the word *Uhr*, the question is "um wieviel Uhr".

Second, the verb has to come in second position here. Questions basically start with the verb, but the question word for *when* precedes this. I won't go into details here, but that's the reason why "um welche Uhrzeit" comes first.

So, there are certainly a lot of possibilities to ask this question. To my mind a very natural way is:

> Um wieviel Uhr können wir uns am Dienstag treffen?

I'm having a hard time phrasing a question which combines all the elements that you tried to put into that sentence (i.e. "wann" + "ist es möglich" + "uns zu treffen"). At least I can't come up with something that sounds natural to me. I don't feel that the following sentence is natural

> Um wieviel Uhr am Dienstag ist es möglich, um uns zu treffen?

I would rather go with a *dass*-clause. But then you'd drop "zu".

> Um wieviel Uhr am Dienstag ist es möglich, dass wir uns treffen?

A natural way to use *zu* + infinitive that I can come up with right now, is something along this:

> Wir sollten den Dienstag nutzen, um uns zu treffen. Um wieviel Uhr ist es möglich?

Comment: Vielen dank für Ihre spezifische Erklärung )

Comment: "Um wieviel Uhr am Dienstag ist es möglich, um uns zu treffen?" - "... möglich, um ..." ergibt ohnehin nicht viel Sinn. Ohne das "um" wäre der Satz etwas besser, auch wenn er dann noch sehr förmlich klänge.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Vermutlich lag es daran, warum es mir so schwer fiel, bzw. unmöglich war, einen gescheiten Satz zu bilden. "Um" gehört hier tatsächlich gestrichen, ohne "um" fühlt er sich aber immer noch genau so schlecht an.

Comment: Und man kann die "Uhr" je nach nachZiel der Frage evtl. komplett weglassen: "Wann" in Kombination mit dem Tag ergibt automatisch die Frage nach der nächstkleineren Einheit, also "Wann können wir uns am Dienstag treffen?". Erlaubt allerdings auch Antworten wie "nach dem Mittagessen".